# How to get un-editable text displaying in iPhone settings display

Tags: ios

I've been able to add an entry to the settings display for my iPhone app, but that text is editable and I don't want that.  I want it to show up such that it's a rounded text bar and on the left it shows "My favorite color is.."  and on the right it always shows "Green"

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html):

> The title type displays a read-only string value. You can use this type to display read-only preference values. (If the preference contains cryptic or nonintuitive values, this type lets you map the possible values to custom strings.)
>
> The key for this type is PSTitleValueSpecifier.

Comment: My trouble was that I had to add the DefaultValue key to it.  Couldn't seem to do that through the GUI, just went to the plist source directly.  Thanks!

Comment: Same trouble -- nothing would display until I added a DefaultValue key. Thanks!